# Add textarea to table based on SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a DB with a list of grocery products across many categories. In each category there is a product called "OTHER". The products display in a table based on search criteria / category selection. I want "OTHER" to appear with a textarea next to it so the user can add details to their order. Here is the PHP for the product display:

```
public function view_front_products() {

$id=  grocery::cs($_GET['id']);

if(isset($_GET['id']))  {
$sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE catid='$id' ORDER BY  name ASC") or die(mysql_error());

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

  echo '
    <form action="?page=addtolist" id="form3" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td class="first">'.$r['name'].' '.'-'.' '.$r['desc'].' </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$r['id'].'">
        <input type="hidden" name="pname" value="'.$r['name'].'">
        <input type="hidden" name="rid" value="'.$id.'">
        <td class="qty"><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="" required /></td>
        <td class="add"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to List" /></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  ';
  }
 }
}
```

I am thinking of something along the lines of

```
 SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name="OTHER";
```

then storing the result in a variable and creating an `if else` to say if the product name is OTHER then display a textarea and if not then don't. Will this work or is there a better way?

Comment: Does the form around each tr actually submit data as expected? I've had trouble with that before

Comment: There's more wrong with this than I can fix in a reasonable amount of time.  Some tips: 1) I think you'll want to do this with JS, 2) Your `form` element should not go outside your `tr`, because that's not valid HTML, 3) mysql_query is deprecated.  Use mysqli_query instead.  Good luck!

Comment: everything submits and handles as expected. this code is from an established site that has worked properly for years. i know the code is dodgey and outdated, and yes I know that mysql_query is deprecated, we just haven't gotten to updating yet. Just looking for a fix for now. @StevenMoseley do you have a suggestion for using JS?

Comment: @Tom - Not only is it using deprecated logic - it looks prone to SQL injection, as well.  "Worked properly for years" doesn't mean it will continue to do so.